# How to integrate a custom test folder with Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unit-testing, gradle

I have an android project with android specific and platform independent code neatly separated:

```
my-project
├── ...
├── build.gradle
├── myapp
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── src
│   ...
└── mymodel
    ├── build.gradle //2
    ├── src
    │   ├── main
    │   |── test
    │   └── otherTests
    │   ...
```

I've recently added a second test folder in model. With [this blog post](https://blog.inspeerity.com/gradle/integration-and-unit-separate-gradle-tasks/) as guidance I've extended `build.gradle` (2) to its current form:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

//* for debug of creating jar
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.3'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.3'

    testImplementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
}

//making otherTests work
sourceSets {
    othertests {
        java.srcDir "$projectDir/src/otherTests/java"
        resources.srcDir "$projectDir/src/otherTests/resources"
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
}

configurations {
    othertestsImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    othertestsRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
task otherTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.othertests.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.othertests.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn otherTest
```

The following work:

- Android studio recognizes the directory structure in `otherTests` as packages and the files as classes
- `gradle otherTests` executes. That implies that gradle can resolve the dependencies to junit and the apache library.

But android studio cannot resolve Types from apache and annotations from junit.

[image: FileUtils]

[image: junit]

I get suggestions:
`Add library Gradle: commons-io:commons-io:2.4 to classpath` and
`Add library Gradle: junit:junit:4.11' to classpath`

but when I click on them or press Alt+Shift+Enter nothing happens. How can I get Android Studio to recognize the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem can usually be solved by *File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart*. If that does not help you can also try close Android Studio, delete the `.idea` directory inside your project directory and then restart Android Studio.